Code works until I try to loop it - infinite sequence?
I am trying to plot how the wavelength of visible light changes with depth in the ocean.
I'm having trouble with my code when trying to loop through a list of files to plot each one. The code runs indefinitely and produces an unexpected output of numbers rather than the plot. Specifically, I've tried to loop through the files to plot each one individually and save them with a unique identifier.
Here's the code that works for one file:
# Create an empty list to store the results 
spec_bats_ng_normalised_long <- list()

# Loop through each dataframe in the list 
for (i in seq_along(spec_bats_ng_normalised)) {
   # Reshape the current dataframe into long format   
   long_df <- spec_bats_ng_normalised[[i]] %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -`depth(m)`, names_to = "Wavelength", values_to = "Intensity")
        
   long_df$Wavelength <- as.numeric(long_df$Wavelength)  
   # Append the long dataframe to the list   
   spec_bats_ng_normalised_long[[i]] <- long_df 
}

depth_intervals <- seq(0, 200, by = 10)  

# Create the plot outside the loop 
spec_bats_ng_plot <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(400,700,by = 50)) +
  theme_minimal()  

# Loop over depth intervals and add layers to the plot 
for (depth in depth_intervals) {
   # Find the index of the closest depth to the one in depth_intervals   
   closest_index <- which.min(abs(spec_bats_ng_normalised_long[[1]]$`depth(m)` - depth))  
   # Extract the closest depth value   
   closest_depth <- spec_bats_ng_normalised_long[[1]]$`depth(m)`[closest_index]   
   # Filter data for the closest depth   
   filtered_data <- filter(spec_bats_ng_normalised_long[[1]], `depth(m)` == closest_depth)   
   # Add layers to the plot   
   spec_bats_ng_plot <- spec_bats_ng_plot +
     geom_line(data = filtered_data, aes(colour = rev(`depth(m)`), x = Wavelength, y = Intensity)) +
     labs(title = "Spectral Intensity for PAR with depth - BATS (No Gaussian)",
          x = "Wavelength (nm)", y = "Intensity (normalised to surface Irradiance)")
}

# Print the final plot 
print(spec_bats_ng_plot + labs(colour = "Depth (m)", breaks = depth_intervals))  
ggsave("SpecE_BATS_No_G.jpg",spec_bats_ng_plot,width = 12, height = 6, dpi = 300)

And here's the loop I've attempted:
# Create an empty list to store the results 
spec_bats_ng_normalised_long <- list()

# Loop through each dataframe in the list 
for (i in seq_along(spec_bats_ng_normalised)) {
   # Reshape the current dataframe into long format   
   long_df <- spec_bats_ng_normalised[[i]] %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -`depth(m)`, names_to = "Wavelength", values_to = "Intensity")
        
   long_df$Wavelength <- as.numeric(long_df$Wavelength)  
   # Append the long dataframe to the list   
   spec_bats_ng_normalised_long[[i]] <- long_df 
}

depth_intervals <- seq(0, 150, by = 10)  

# Create the plot outside the loop 
spec_bats_ng_plot <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(400,700,by = 50)) +
  theme_minimal()  

# Loop over each spectral element within the list 
for (spec_data in spec_bats_ng_normalised_long){   
  # Loop over depth intervals and add layers to the plot   
  for (depth in depth_intervals) {     
    # Find the index of the closest depth to the one in depth_intervals     
    closest_index <- which.min(abs(spec_data$`depth(m)` - depth))          
    # Extract the closest depth value     
    closest_depth <- spec_data$`depth(m)`[closest_index]          
    # Filter data for the closest depth     
    filtered_data <- filter(spec_data, `depth(m)` == closest_depth)          
    # Add layers to the plot     
    spec_bats_ng_plot <- spec_bats_ng_plot +
      geom_line(data = filtered_data, aes(colour = `depth(m)`, x = Wavelength, y = Intensity)) +
      labs(title = paste("Spectral Intensity for PAR with depth - BATS (No Gaussian)",i),
           x = "Wavelength (nm)", y = "Intensity (normalised to surface Irradiance)")
  }  
}

# Print the final plot 
print(spec_bats_ng_plot + labs(colour = "Depth (m)", breaks = depth_intervals))
ggsave("SpecE_BATS_No_G.jpg",spec_bats_ng_plot,width = 12, height = 6, dpi = 300)

Any advice on how to modify the loop to correctly plot each file and save them separately would be appreciated!
Here is the head of spec_bats_ng_normalised which I use in both sections of code:

As requested here is the dput of my list:

> dput(limited_list[[1]][1:5, 1:5])
structure(list(`depth(m)` = c(0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4, 3.2), `400` = c(1, 
0.972531036836584, 0.945817414828785, 0.919838341546468, 0.894573597461042
), `405` = c(1, 0.974393076923276, 0.949442566850803, 0.925131625134213, 
0.901443839849326), `410` = c(1, 0.975436719339077, 0.951477439563053, 
0.928107292566113, 0.905311776650204), `415` = c(1, 0.976315609524299, 
0.953192772729279, 0.930618160888521, 0.908578761970095)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")


You can make it much easier for people to help you if you can make your question reproducible, where you share some sample data has the form of your real data, so that we can actually run the code. Can you run dput(limited_list[[1]][1:5, 1:5]) and paste the output into your question? That will make a code "recipe" that will faithfully recreate the first 5 rows and columns of the first element of your limited_list object, structure and data formats and all.

@JonSpring done! Hope that makes it clearer - thanks!
